# SQL Azure connection string speed (IP or domain)

Tags: sql, azure, connection-string, azure-sql-database

Until now we always use an IP address in our connection string to the SQL. This way we think it will be faster because the user doesn't need to find the IP of the domain.

Now we are trying Microsoft Azure and we see that they use a domain name in the connection string.

Will be slower? sometimes we know it takes 100-400 milliseconds to resolve a domain name to an IP address, do we spend this time every reload of the page?

Comment: Do you type in an IP address instead of www.google.com when you want to visit Google? What problem are you having that requires you to forego DNS resolution? Do you connect and disconnect a lot and somehow connection pooling isn't good enough?

Answer (score 2):

You need to access SQL Azure by the given server name, as you're connecting to a massive-scale system, not a single computer. Regarding delay on page load: I don't know how you architected your solution, but reloading a web page does not equate to re-establishing a database connection from web app to database.

Answer (score 0):

The DNS resolution will be cached - it doesn't have to do a new look up each time. You can prove this by using resolving a DNS entry programatically via [System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses.aspx) on a test page.

Edit: It will be cached by the calling server(s).

Comment: It will cache on the user computer or in the server? if it will cache on the user computer others users will always need to resolved the domain. thanks